# Is there a good tutorial for implementing an augmented reality iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, camera, augmented-reality

Are there any good tutorials or sample applications out there that demonstrate how to make an augmented reality iPhone application?

Comment: As i am a beginner in iphone development,from where should i start learning about augumented reality.

Answer (score 28):

I doubt exactly such a thing exists, but what you need to do is look at the location and camera frameworks for the iPhone, and go from there.

Basically, you will create a UIImagePickerController (the Camera class) and overlay information on the view, via a custom .cameraOverlayView (which is a property of    UIImagePickerController in 3.0).

You will probably want to get    information (location, heading, distance, etc.) from the GPS of the    device, using the CoreLocation framework.

You will also probably want to do some web server interactions, and for that I suggest ASIHTTPRequest.

Those are the basic tools needed to build an AR application.

Comment: Adding to Andrew's answer, As on date, there isn't any live image processing libraries. so, what most augmented reality apps do is, augment information based on location and compass direction.

Answer (score 9):

Question is old i know. Just for the sake of completion:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/3997/introduction-to-augmented-reality-on-the-iphone

Answer (score 8):

Here is an iphone AR project hosted on github: http://github.com/zac/iphonearkit/

Haven't used it myself though.

Answer (score 5):

Check this:
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-game-development/38119-augmented-reality-ar.html
You will find a tutorial and a sample :).
Good Luck!

Answer (score 5):

there is a GPL (free and open source) augmented reality browser for iPhone: mixare augmented reality engine.
You can find the code in gthub: https://github.com/mixare/mixare-iphone/
and use-cases and more info on the website: http://www.mixare.org

Best,
Daniele

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to make an AR application for iPhone 3.1 that does live image processing (I've done one for myself).
Here is a good tutorial with working sample code for 2.x http://www.morethantechnical.com/2009/07/01/augmented-reality-on-the-iphone-using-nyartoolkit-w-code/

For 3.1, you'll need to replace the camera video grabbing code. Tip: PLCameraController _createPreviewIOSurface.

Note that you can't submit such apps to the App Store because of the use of private API.

Answer (score 3):

I found one too

http://www.3dar.us/docs/tutorials/add-3dar-to-your-app-in-5-minutes/?gclid=CM2Stpr64KoCFQsh6wod906E7Q

It has the source code at github which is linked at the end of the page.