# Augmented Reality for IPhone

Tags: iphone, augmented-reality

I want to design an Iphone game using Augmented Reality but I dont have Pre experience in this field I dont know from where to start so could any one please suggest some links, tutorials, pdf anything to start from scratch..
Please help !!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a good tutorial for implementing an augmented reality iPhone application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084327/is-there-a-good-tutorial-for-implementing-an-augmented-reality-iphone-applicatio)

Answer (score 9):

Check out this [iPhone-ARKitDemo](https://github.com/nielswh/iPhone-AR-Toolkit) or [this one](https://github.com/zac/iphonearkit) on github.

Theres also [NyARToolkit](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2009/07/01/augmented-reality-on-the-iphone-using-nyartoolkit-w-code/).

Or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084327/augmented-reality-iphone-tutorial/2084401#2084401) on SO.

[iOS 4 Sensor Programming: Augmented Reality and Location Enabled iPhone and iPad Apps](http://www.ipadaccessoriesonlinestore.com/ipad-books/ios-4-sensor-programming-augmented-reality-and-location-enabled-iphone-and-ipad-apps/)

Here is a PDF: [iPhone Augmented Reality Games](http://amandarosler.com/Amanda_Rosler_Augmented_Reality_Games_on_the_iPhone.pdf)

Here is a PDF: [Augmented Reality for Travel](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=12&ved=0CB0QFjABOAo&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mtrip.com%2Fpress%2Freleases%2Ftravel-augmented-reality.pdf&ei=l6cmTdqwJJGosAPsmZGhBw&usg=AFQjCNGX_7qeYzXix8pOnGk0XrZjTKvfHA&sig2=75fMTLaStnratEgULmTQxQ) on iPhone

Here is a PDF: [Mobile Augmented Reality](http://juniperresearch.com/shop/products/report/pdf/contents/8437Mobile%20Augmented%20Reality%20-%20TOC.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3997/introduction-to-augmented-reality-on-the-iphone
This might a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Check out free [Mobile SDK](http://www.metaio.com/software/mobile-sdk/) by metaio. In addition to native iOS development, it also offers [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/) plugin for games development on iOS and Android.