# Augmented reality iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, augmented-reality

Is there any  sample "augmented reality" app for iPhone or iPod?

Comment: You'll want to accept answers to the questions you've asked. You'll find that people are more willing to answer your questions when you do so..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Augmented Reality for IPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622786). Please search before asking. Did you see the previous augmented reality questions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Augmented reality on iphone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716201/augmented-reality-on-iphone)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Wikitude API for augmented reality in iPhone app. For integrating this API in your application you will have to use their API Key which you can get by registering over here http://w4client.mobilizy.mobi/w4/jsp/keyGenerator.jsp (direct link).

You can download this API from http://www.wikitude.org/developers

Answer (score 0):

You can explore applications like.. 
a) Vuforia -  vuforia.com 
b) Wikitude - javascript sdk and native iOS sdk also avail 
c) ARToolKit - https://artoolkit.org 
b) Blippar - blippar.com/download 
d) Augment - http://www.augment.com/