# Augmented reality API for iPhone

Tags: iphone, augmented-reality

I want to implement augmented reality application for iPhone. Would anyone provide any API or sample code which help me to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a good tutorial for implementing an augmented reality iPhone application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084327/is-there-a-good-tutorial-for-implementing-an-augmented-reality-iphone-application)

Comment: See also [Augmented Reality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921895/augmented-reality) and [Augmented Reality for IPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622786/augmented-reality-for-iphone).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Augmented reality on iphone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716201/augmented-reality-on-iphone)

Comment: This [AR framework](https://github.com/zac/iphonearkit/) was recommended in an answer. That is likely to be deleted, so preserving it here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Wikitude API for augmented reality in iPhone app and for integrating this API in your application you will have to use their API Key which you can get by registering over here http://w4client.mobilizy.mobi/w4/jsp/keyGenerator.jsp (Direct link).

You can download this API from http://developer.wikitude.com/download

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [link](http://dev.metaio.com/sdk/getting-started/next-steps/ios/) to a tutorial with sample code, screen shots etc. It's for using the metaio SDK. The free download file is on the left.