# Augmented reality visor iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, camera, augmented-reality

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is there a good tutorial for implementing an augmented reality iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084327/is-there-a-good-tutorial-for-implementing-an-augmented-reality-iphone-application)
>   [Augmented Reality for IPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622786/augmented-reality-for-iphone)

Hi all, If I have the long and lat of points I'm just wondering how hard and how I go about overlaying them on a camera input on the iPhone? Like how the Layar app does it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See also [Augmented Reality for IPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622786/augmented-reality-for-iphone)

Answer (score 2):

The cameraOverlayView property of the UIImagePickerController is what you're looking for.