# any example augmented reality in iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad

any code best tutorial or code available for the augmented reality in iphone?
I am facing lots of problem with the capturing of image with attaching other image on that.
add any overlay or something.
any sample code is more then appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a good tutorial for implementing an augmented reality iPhone application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084327/is-there-a-good-tutorial-for-implementing-an-augmented-reality-iphone-applicatio)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please go through https://github.com/zac/iphonearkit.
It's the best objectiveC code available.

Answer (score 0):

There's a step-by step tutorial from iOS environment setup to tracking and rendering 3D animations here: http://dev.metaio.com/sdk/tutorials/hello-world/

Also includes sample code and 3D assets to play around with.