# Augmented reality on iOS?

Tags: ios, ios5, sdk, augmented-reality

I want to write an augmented reality application on iOS 5.
But I have one problem. I can't find simple implementation code of augmented reality.
I anyone can share the link, please do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a good tutorial for implementing an augmented reality iPhone application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084327/is-there-a-good-tutorial-for-implementing-an-augmented-reality-iphone-applicatio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1273

There is one example of using the camera overlay. However I'm not exactly sure what you're expecting, the question is kind of vague.